# Possible to make browser play a sound file when a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript

For Javascript:

Is it possible for my browser to play some sort of sound/music when a certain image appears? Could it perhaps play an mp3 file in my music library? Right now, the best I can do is:

```
if (document.getElementById("happyface")) {
    window.alert("Attention: Happy face detected.");
    }
```

I should also mention that I have the page constantly refreshing itself, so a loop isn't necessary (at least, I don't think so).

Comment: Page that _"constantly refreshing itself"_ and plays music... sounds like you gonna suffer from too much traffic really soon.

Comment: I tried looking around before asking, but couldn't find much. 
Quentin, is it possible to play a local audio file without importing any additional libraries?

Comment: gdoron, it's not actually my own site, so I don't need to worry about traffic just yet. And the script pauses when the particular image of interest is detected.

Also, I should also mention that this is a "scriptname.user.js" type of file. As an complete amateur, I actually don't know if that's obvious.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to word my question is: "How can I get my userscript in Google Chrome to play my 3 second audio file if (document.location.href == 'http://facebook.com')"?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the audio tag for that:

```
function sound(){
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.src = "your_path_to_soundfile.wav";
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        document.removeChild(this);
    }, false);
    audio.play();   
}

if (document.getElementById("happyface")) {
    sound();
}
```

Comment: I think that exactly what I'm looking for, but the only problem is that I can't seem to get it to start. This pops up in the console:

"Not allowed to load local resource: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Admin/Music/bicycle_bell.wav "

Comment: You cannot access local filesystem by default from javascript. Try the code with a weblink to a sound like "http://yourpath.com/sound.wav"